# Why are the build settings not appearing in my Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build, hololens

I'm using Visual Studio to build a program for HoloLens with Unity.

I need to deploy .nbin files with my program into my device. I've come to know that we need to change build settings to "content" for them to be deployed. But the option just doesn't appear in the solution explorer window.

The things I've tried were

1. I set the platform to Universal Windows Platform in Unity.
2. Changed(Reset) the import and export settings to General.

But none of them seems to work. Any other way/settings i need to change for the option to appear?

Here are a couple of screenshots of the [Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vhOw.jpg) and [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kURYM.jpg) Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Id have thought they would live in plugins or resources